# Bounding $\langle \theta, w\rangle$ given that $\sum \theta_i^2 / \mu_i^2 \leq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Consider two sequences in $\ell_2$, $\{\theta_i\}_i^\infty$ and $\{\mu_i\}_i^\infty$ where $\mu_i > 0$ and $\sum_i^\infty \frac{\theta_i^2}{\mu_i^2} \leq 1$.

Given another sequence $\{w_i\}_i^\infty$ (not necessarily in $\ell_2$), I want an upper  bound on:

$$\sum_i^\infty w_i \theta_i$$

Of course, cauchy schwarz gives us an upper bound $\|w\|_2\|\theta\|_2$, but this bound is too coarse since we don't even know if $w$ is in $\ell_2$.

How can I use the information that $\sum_i^\infty \frac{\theta_i^2}{\mu_i^2} \leq 1$ to give a better bound?

Comment: You don't have any information at all on the sequence $(w_i)$ ? Hard to find an upper bound if it doesn't have any regularity.

Comment: I think that this is way too vague, and so there's nothing that could be said (without further qualifications). Can you state the motivation behind asking this question, which might give more information about the strucutre of $w$?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I didn't want to give too many details since it could solve my problem without effort from me (usually people on this site like to give complete solutions even if you insist on only wanting a hint). In my case $w_i \stackrel{\sim}{iid} N(0, 1)$ and I want to bound $\mathbb E \sup \langle \theta, w\rangle$ in terms of $\|\mu\|$. My answer below allows me to do that since I know that $\mathbb E \|w\| \leq \sqrt n$ for finite $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension of what you've done with Cauchy-schwarz:

Notice that $\phi(x, y) = x/y$ is a convex function for $x\geq 0, y >0$. Next, consider the first $n$ elements of each sequence and apply Jensen's inequality:

$$n \frac{{\sum_i^n \theta_i^2}}{ {\sum_i^n \mu_i^2}}\leq \sum_i^n \frac{\theta_i^2}{\mu_i^2} \leq 1$$

So that:

$$n {\sum_i^n \theta_i^2} \leq {\sum_i^n \mu_i^2}$$

Then continuing where you left off (but considering only finite $n$) and applying our bound involving $\mu$:

$$\sum_i^n \theta_i w_i \leq \sqrt {\sum_i^n \theta_i^2} \sqrt {\sum_i^n w_i^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt {\sum_i^n \mu_i^2}}{\sqrt n} \sqrt {\sum_i^n w_i^2}$$

So that if $\sqrt {\sum_i^n w_i} = O(\sqrt n)$ then the whole sequence is $O(\sqrt {\sum_i^n \mu_i^2})$.